# Firewall & DNS issue

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, windows-firewall

Server: Windows Server 2008 R2

When firewall is running on the DC no machines can resolve DNS which is running on the DC. It also prevents AD user logins. It also prevents Group Policy update.

According to the firewall rules DNS is allowed on all ports as well as AD rules etc.

Any ideas why the firewall is still blocking?

Comment: Are the rules tied to the applicable firewall profile? What tests did you do to draw your conclusions? You really need to post your actual config and the exact tests and results, or the question turns too broad.

Comment: The DNS service plays important role in AD. In short: no DNS, no AD. Try running nslookup tool from a workstation and try to resolve AD Domain Name, the DC etc. Also Windows firewall has extensive log. Take a look at it.